# Test class for importing a csv file

Tags: apex, unit-test

Here i am tried to write a test class for importing csv file.THere is no code coverage.Plese help me on this.

```
public class adminPriorSale {
    public list<Distributor_Prior_Sales__c> accon{get;set;}
    public Distributor_Prior_Sales__c agnt{get;set;}
    public Integer PriorSale{set;get;}
    public id tobeEdited{get; set;} 
    public string deleteid{get;set;}
    public boolean editSection {get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController stand;
    Public String retURL{get;set;}
    //To import file
    public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
    public string csvAsString{get;set;}
    public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}

    public adminPriorSale(apexpages.standardcontroller controller )
   {

     retURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
     this.stand=controller;
     tobeEdited = controller.getId();
     agnt = new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c();
     accon = New List<Distributor_Prior_Sales__c>(); 
     accon= [select id,Name,SMS_sales_amount__c,SMS_Year__c,Customer__c,Calculation_Type__c from Distributor_Prior_Sales__c]; 

     csvFileLines = new String[]{};

     }


public PageReference EdittheSection()
     {
       PageReference ref=new PageReference('/apex/adminPriorSale1?retURL=/apex/Admin');
       ref.setRedirect(true);
       update accon;
       return ref;
       }

   private void LoadData()
       {
           accon= [select id,Name,SMS_sales_amount__c,SMS_Year__c,Customer__c,Calculation_Type__c from Distributor_Prior_Sales__c WHERE (owner.id =: userinfo.getuserid())];
       }

       // Import CSV file to list of record

        public void importCSVFile(){

       try{
           csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
           csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 
           for(Integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
               Distributor_Prior_Sales__c prisale = new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c () ;
               string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
               prisale.SMS_Year__c= csvRecordData[0] ;             
               prisale.SMS_sales_amount__c= Decimal.valueof(csvRecordData[1]);
               prisale.Customer__c= csvRecordData[2];
               prisale.Calculation_Type__c = csvRecordData[3];   
               accon.add(prisale); 

           }
        upsert accon;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
        } 

  }    


    public void save1()
        {
         update accon;
        }
     public void DeleteSale()
       {

        Distributor_Prior_Sales__c del_task=new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c(id=deleteid);
        delete del_task;
        accon=[select id,Name,SMS_sales_amount__c,SMS_Year__c,Customer__c,Calculation_Type__c from Distributor_Prior_Sales__c];

        }


     public pagereference saveRecord()
     {
        List<Distributor_Prior_Sales__c> discLocal=accon.clone() ;
        List<Distributor_Prior_Sales__c> discLocal2=new List<Distributor_Prior_Sales__c>(accon);
         integer i=0;
        for(Distributor_Prior_Sales__c sale:accon){

               if(sale.SMS_sales_amount__c==null && sale.SMS_Year__c ==null && sale.Customer__c ==null && sale.Calculation_Type__c==null  )
               { discLocal2.remove(i); }

               else if(sale.SMS_sales_amount__c==null || sale.SMS_Year__c ==null || sale.Customer__c ==null || sale.Calculation_Type__c==null )
               {
               ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'You must enter all required fields');
               ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
               return null;
              }
              i++;
           }
          upsert discLocal2; 
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/adminPriorSale?retURL=/apex/Admin');
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        return pageref; 
      }

     public PageReference cancel()  
     {
      PageReference pg1=new PageReference('/apex/adminPriorSale?retURL=/apexAdmin');
      pg1.setRedirect(true);
      return pg1;
     }  
   public void addrow() {

        Distributor_Prior_Sales__c proSale = new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c();
        proSale.SMS_sales_amount__c= (agnt.SMS_sales_amount__c);
        proSale.SMS_Year__c =(agnt.SMS_Year__c );
        proSale.Customer__c=(agnt.Customer__c);
        proSale.Calculation_Type__c=(agnt.Calculation_Type__c);

        accon.add(proSale );
       }  
     }
```

And it test class is

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
private class test_adminPriorSale {
    static testMethod void test_adminPriorSale()
    { 
        Distributor_Prior_Sales__c   t1= new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c  ();
        t1.Name='test1';
        t1.SMS_sales_amount__c =123;
        t1.SMS_Year__c='2012';
        insert t1;

        String csvContent = 'test1',123,'2012','I Architects','Estimated Prior sales';

        PageReference pageRef = Page.adminPriorSale; // Adding VF page Name here
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(t1.id));//for page reference
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('RecordType','adminPriorSale');
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(t1);
        adminPriorSale controller = new adminPriorSale(sc);

        controller.save1();
        controller.saveRecord();
        controller.addrow();
        controller.DeleteSale();
        controller.editSection = true;
        controller.EdittheSection();
        //controller.LoadData();
        controller.cancel();
        controller.importCSVFile();

    }
    static testMethod void test_adminPriorSale2()
    { 
        Distributor_Prior_Sales__c   t1= new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c  ();
        t1.Name='test1';
        //t1.SMS_sales_amount__c =123;
        //t1.SMS_Year__c='2014';
        insert t1;

        Distributor_Prior_Sales__c   t2= new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c  ();
        t2.Name='test1';
        t2.SMS_sales_amount__c =123;
        t2.SMS_Year__c='2014';
        insert t2;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.adminPriorSale; // Adding VF page Name here
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(t1.id));//for page reference
        pageRef.getParameters().put('retURL', String.valueOf(t1.id));//for page reference
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('RecordType','adminPriorSale');
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(t1);
        adminPriorSale controller = new adminPriorSale(sc);
        controller.saveRecord();
        controller.cancel();
    }

    static testMethod void test_adminPriorSale3()
    { 
        Distributor_Prior_Sales__c   t1= new Distributor_Prior_Sales__c  ();
        t1.Name='test1';
        //t1.SMS_sales_amount__c =123;
        //t1.SMS_Year__c='2014';
        insert t1;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.adminPriorSale; // Adding VF page Name here
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(t1.id));//for page reference
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('RecordType','adminPriorSale');
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(t1);
        adminPriorSale controller = new adminPriorSale(sc);
        controller.cancel();
        controller.editSection = true;
        controller.EdittheSection();
    }

}
```

It is giving 64% code coverage.not covering the importing csv file part.someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 7):

You code never actually get the CSV from anywhere:

You declare:

```
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
```

Then later you:

```
csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
```

Within a try catch block so it throws an error as you never actually set the value of the csvFileBody

**NOTE** This is WHY assertions in test classes are extremely important. You are concerned with covering lines but if you were asserting results, for example, when executing IMportCSVFile in your test, assert that there are no page messages and query and assert that Distributor_Prior_Sales__c records were created. In doing that you would know that it is actually working or not (error thrown since in try catch) instead of just covering lines.